# Распознать текст с обработанного изображения opencv

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2


def find_number(input_img, k):
    haar_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascade.xml')
    dim = (int(input_img.shape[1]*k), int(input_img.shape[0] * k))
    resized_img = cv2.resize(input_img, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    gray_scale_img = cv2.cvtColor(resized_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    pictures = haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_scale_img, scaleFactor=1.40, minNeighbors=15, minSize=(20, 20))
    recognized = []
    for (x, y, w, h) in pictures:
        cv2.rectangle(resized_img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        recognized.append(resized_img[y:y + h, x:x + w])
    return recognized


img = cv2.imread('test/26.jpg')
images = find_number(img, 0.9)
if len(images) > 0:
    for i in range(len(images)):
        cv2.imshow(str(i), images[i])
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Код обрабатывает изображение, выводя автомобильный номер в качестве картинки.
Нужно считать этот номер непосредственной с обработанной картинки.
Каким образом это сделать? Уже и через pytesseract и easyocr пытался, ничего дельного не получалось.

Comment: Это - задача распознавания образов. Используйте тогда TenzorFlow, например. На Github для этого библиотеки есть готовые. Несколько странно, что для pytesseract распознавание дорожных знаков специально выделено, как одна из основных задач, а у вас не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Что бы не марочить мозги с библиотеками, вы можете воспользоваться api

```py
import requests
def orc(url):
    r = requests.post('https://api.ocr.space/parse/image', data={'url': url, 'isOverlayRequired': False, 'apikey': 'helloworld', "OCREngine": "2"})
    return False if r.json()["IsErroredOnProcessing"] == True else r.json()["ParsedResults"][0]["ParsedText"].replace(" ", "")



test_url = orc('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/952990044539473980/953680748257370112/capha-1.png')
print(test_url)
```

Comment: Как мне поместить туда уже обработанное изображение?

Comment: Как мне в api добавлять моё изображение?